# IO Throttling After Reaching dirty_background_ratio

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, io, cache, sysctl

I am trying to understand the Linux IO throttling mechanism. This is what I got so far:

By calling the `write (fd, data, size)` system call, the data will be written into the OS cache as dirty pages. The OS has two ratios, `dirty_background_ratio` and `dirty_ratio` to manage the dirty pages. The OS starts background flushes when the dirty pages reach the `dirty_background_ratio`. The `dirty_ratio` is the hard limit that the OS prevents to be exceeded.

If the amount of the dirty pages is less than the `dirty_background_ratio`, the application (that performs IO) will not be delayed by the OS and the data is simply written on the OS cache as dirty pages (*freerun*). If the dirty pages exceed `dirty_background_ratio`, the OS performs background flushes and cleans the dirty pages asynchronously. Though, if I'm correct, still no throttling should occur until reaching the `set_point = (dirty_ratio + dirty_background_ratio) / 2`. To my understanding, the OS tries to keep the dirty ratio around the `set_point`. This is what I found in the [*Wu Fengguang*'s commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/mm/page-writeback.c?id=143dfe8611a63030ce0c79419dc362f7838be557) of the Linux kernel:

> Users will notice that the applications will get throttled once crossing the global (background + dirty)/2 = 15% threshold, and then balanced around 17.5%.

To actually confirm these points, I implemented a simple application in C which generates  `65 GB` IO data in `1 GB` write chunks (using the `write` system call). At the same time, I measure the bandwidth (throughput, throttled time), the number of dirty pages, and compute the dirty ratio by dividing the number of dirty pages to `dirtyable memory = free memory + reclaimable + file cache` (according to [global_dirtyable_memory](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.16/source/mm/page-writeback.c#L356)).

My system (CPU: Xeon 6138, RAM: `192 GB`) runs CentOS Linux 7 (Core) with the kernel version `3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64`. The IO destination is an SSD device with `400 MB/s` write bandwidth. Before running the experiment, I call the [*sync*](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sync) command and wait so that all dirty pages from before are flushed (you see the global dirty ratio is almost zero at the beginning). The experiments are performed on a clean state system (no other dirtier/expensive processes, only OS management related processes running on the system). Here are my measurements:

[image: IO Throughput / Dirty Pages]

The *x-ax* shows the *n-th* write of `1 GB` data. The measurements match quite well with the computed rates (`dirty_background_ratio = 10%`, `set_point = 15%`, `balanced around 17.5%`). But every time I run the experiment (also on other storage devices), I see a reduced bandwidth after reaching the `dirty_background_ratio`. You can see this on the red area in the picture. According to what I read on different sources (e.g. the point mentioned above by *Wu Fengguang*), no throttling should occur until reaching `set_point`. Whereas I see the throttling starts when reaching `dirty_background_ratio` and stays steady until reaching `set_point` where the throttling increases very fast and converges to the disk write bandwidth (sync performance, `400 MB/s`).

So here is my question: Why do I experience throttled IO before reaching the `set_point` (red area)? And how does the OS determine the amount of throttling **before** reaching `set_point`?

---

I asked this question a while ago. In the comments, user495217 wrote that this may be the side effects of the background activity of OS. I wanted to know if this is the case, and if so, does anyone know any resources that already discussed this point? or does someone have any suggestions to  run an experiment that can prove this? I have measured the number of CPU Instructions and cycles per second during IO, and have not observed any changes that can prove this.

Comment: Are you looking at the dirty pages for just your process, or the *global* dirty pages?  What you see as early throttling might just be the system slowing your process in fairness to other things on the system, or from another perspective, it isn't early when you consider dirty pages from other things.  At peak bandwidth, dirty pages from other things might already be flushed, or might be lost in the noise.

Comment: I am looking at the global dirty pages. But I run the process on a clean state (no other dirtier/expensive processes, only OS management related processes running). Another point that makes me certain this has noting to do with other processes is that I experience this effect every time I repeat the experiment exactly at the same time. The same holds also for other storage devices I have (e.g. an HDD disk).

Comment: Additionally, before each experiment, I call the _sync_ command and wait to flush all dirty pages before running the experiment. As you see, at the beginning of the experiment, the dirty ratio is almost zero.

Comment: At 10% (dirty_background_ratio) the flushing of dirty pages starts, which indirectly slightly impedes other processes. But then the hard limit is hit and the kernel actively throttles writers. This makes the rate drop from 2.5/2.0 G to 0.4 G.  Your graphs look good but lacks hard data.